# How to color a leaflet map by a categorical variable?

Tags: r, leaflet, maps

Using leafleat, how can I color the different areas based on 'NAME_ASCI' and show colors on a legend?

This works:

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
m <- leaflet(franconia) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addFeatures(.)
m
```

But when I try to color dynamically it doesn't work. Where the color argument should go?

```
m <- leaflet(franconia, color = ~ RdYlBu(NAME_ASCI)) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addFeatures(.)
m

# With mapview I use 'zcol' to accomplish the colors

mapview(franconia, zcol = "NAME_ASCI")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter I would suggest to have a look at the docs on [colors](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html) and [legends](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html). `color` is an attribute of the `addXXX` functions.

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)

colors <- colorRampPalette(
  RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu")
)(length(levels(franconia$NAME_ASCI)))

pal <- leaflet::colorFactor(colors,
  domain = levels(franconia$NAME_ASCI)
)

leaflet(franconia) %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addPolygons(
    color = ~ pal(NAME_ASCI),
    fillOpacity = 1, stroke = FALSE
  ) %>%
  addLegend(
    pal = pal,
    values = ~NAME_ASCI,
    opacity = 1
  )
```

[image]